# REST API Link to edit excel/word doc online

Tags: rest, excel, word, office365apis

I am using the O365 REST API to display/organise files and currently xls/doc files have to be downloaded then opened in an editor in order to edit them.

Is there a way to open these in the Word/Excel online editor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wopiframe.

For example:

http://sharep.xxx:8080/sites/"site"/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%2Fsites%2F"site"%2FShared%20Documents%2FTitle%2Edocx&action=edit